# Unable to restore the database with the query

Tags: sql-server, restore

```
USE master
GO
ALTER DATABASE Tfs_CoE SET SINGLE_USER 
WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE;
GO
RESTORE DATABASE Tfs_CoE
FROM DISK = 'D:\Backupfolder\Tfs_CoE.bak'
WITH MOVE 'Tfs_CoE' TO 'D:\MSSQL12.SQLSERVERSECOND\MSSQL\DATA\Tfs_CoE.mdf',
MOVE 'Tfs_CoE_Log' TO 'D:\MSSQL12.SQLSERVERSECOND\MSSQL\DATA\Tfs_CoE.ldf'
WITH RECOVERY , REPLACE ;
GO
```

Here is the error:

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword `'with'`. If this statement is a common table expression, an xmlnamespaces clause or a change tracking context clause, the previous statement must be terminated with a semicolon.

Comment: Can you test it with out the last `WITH` (the one near `RECOVERY , REPLACE`)  ... last row like this `,RECOVERY , REPLACE ;` ?

Answer (score 4):

```
RESTORE DATABASE 
    Tfs_CoE
FROM 
    DISK = 'D:\Backupfolder\Tfs_CoE.bak'
WITH 
    MOVE 'Tfs_CoE' TO 'D:\MSSQL12.SQLSERVERSECOND\MSSQL\DATA\Tfs_CoE.mdf',
    MOVE 'Tfs_CoE_Log' TO 'D:\MSSQL12.SQLSERVERSECOND\MSSQL\DATA\Tfs_CoE.ldf',
    RECOVERY, 
    REPLACE;
```

See [`RESTORE` (Transact-SQL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186858.aspx) for the full documentation.